# Problem with samba shares / smtp server on local machine after apt-get upgrade

Tags: networking, debian, samba

I have a pressing issue... I was silly and ran apt-get upgrade on our debian domain controller / internal smtp server and now the users (on WinXP & Vista) cannot access the network shares or smtp server. No conf's were changed, I can ping the box from windows, but thats it. I can even see one of the two shares, but cannot access it.

EDIT: smtp server now working, its only the samba shares now.

Any help would be muchly appreciated! Thanks!

Christian

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.

What is the error message in the samba logs? Clear the log and try to connect from your machine.
What version did you upgrade from and to?
Perhaps you can try downgrading just to get things working.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, lets do some basic troubleshooting.

**Step 1** - Is the service runnning?

```
  /etc/init.d/smb status
```

If not, start it
      /etc/init.d/smb start

**Step 2** - Can we connect to it locally

```
  telnet localhost 139
```

If not, check /var/log/samba/* and /var/log/messages to see why it didn't actually start

**Step 3** - Can we connect to it remotely

```
  telnet server.ip.address.x 139
```

If not, check the firewall

```
  iptables -L -n
```

and adjust accordingly

**Step 4** - Does SMBClient let you list the shares

```
  smbclient //localhost -L --user username
```

If not, use the error to help troubleshoot (or post it here)

**Step 5** - Does SMBClient let you list the shrares remotely

```
  smbclient //server.ip.address.x -L --user username
```

If this doesn't work and the previous steps all did, check the firewall again, and check the firewall on the remote systems.

Comment: Thanks! That's sort of my standard "well, something's broke. Lets figure out why" list, just change the appropriate init scripts and log entries ;-)

Comment: I need to create a few of these for when things go wrong... I too quickly become overwhelmed in what I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I ran another upgrade, this time dist-upgrade, restarted samba and now it is working.

All of this and I just wanted to upgrade subversion, which is still not upgraded! Bah! Give me yum anyday... :)

Comment: argh. Glad it's working.

Comment: if you only want to upgrade subversion, then run "apt-get install subversion".  this will upgrade it if it's already installed, or install it if it isn't.  "apt-get dist-upgrade" is telling the system to do a complete upgrade of the distribution.  BTW, a good habit to get into is to run apt-get install or dist-upgrade or whatever with the "-d" (download only) option first so you can see what it's going to do first.  if you like what it's going to do, then run it again without "-d"

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on *what gets upgraded or installed* as you're running apt-get upgrade. (And make sure you run it in interactive mode so you can say no.)

MOST linux upgrades do not require a reboot. My list of 'things I know may require a reboot' includes: upgraded kernel modules or a new kernel, dlm updates, video drivers, and a handfull of other things that I recognize when I see them but can't remember off the top of my head. Part of the 'experience' thing that comes with being a linux sysadmin for x number of years.

Generally, if I know the dependencies for a particular library have been updated, I'll end up restarting some extra services just to make sure they didn't have something cached oddly. For example, when I see an upgrade to openssl, if it doesn't bounce apache, mysql, and openvpn, I'll do that manually really quick just to be on the safe side because all of those server processes use ssl.